# Удалить последние обозначенные буквы в словах строки

Tags: java, строки

Нужна помощь. Нужно удалить последнюю букву "e" в каждом слове строки, если длина слова >1.
Делал через разбивку на массив, вот только привести назад в строку не получается.
Через toCharArray результат похожий.

```
public class RemoveE {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String str = "like row lounge dude top";
        String[] words = str.split("\\s|[,.;:]");
        for (String subStr : words) {
            if (subStr.endsWith("e"))
                subStr = subStr.substring(0, subStr.length() - 1);
            String finalString = new String(subStr);
            System.out.println(finalString);
        }
}
}
```

Comment: В Java8 есть `String.join`

Answer (score 0):

В голову пришел самый простой способ это использование регулярных выражений и `replaceAll`. Получится такой метод:

```
private String removeEndE(String str) {
    return str.replaceAll("\Be\b", "");
}
```

Вывод результата данной функции:

```
System.out.println(removeEndE("12e asd e asd asdade 123e edasd e asde")
```

Вывод:

```
12 asd e asd asdad 123 edasd e asd
```

Пояснение:

Регулярное выражение выделяет все вхождения по следующему шаблону `(не конец слова)e(конец слова)`. А дальше заменяем все найденные подстроки на `""`.

Comment: За наводку спасибо! Еще вопрос: как быть, если после слова стоят знаки препинания?

Comment: Регулярное выражение, проверяет конец слова, она понимает, что знаки препинания это уже не часть слова, можешь поиграть с ней тут https://regex101.com/r/zneTSa/1

Comment: (?<!\b)e\b - вот такая регулярка сработала. Спасибо!